# Konga: How can I provision the admin user account and the Kong connection in the Konga docker image?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kong

I am using [Konga](https://pantsel.github.io/konga/) on a Kubernetes cluster using a Helm chart.

This ends up using **the official Konga image** ([pantsel/konga](https://hub.docker.com/r/pantsel/konga/)), that doesn't seem to support **provisioning** of the admin account or of the Kong connection.

What could be the easiest way to do it?

I am considering injecting this information in its localDb file, `/app/kongadata/konga.db` (which is a JSON file).

Or maybe it could be easier to use the database PostgreSQL?

Thanks.